# [JAVA]Setting swing look and feel causes memory leak when resizing window

Tags: java, linux, swing, memory-leaks, look-and-feel

Building a swing application for a college project, running into a strange issue.

When I set my swing application to use the native look and feel, the memory usage keeps on increasing when I resize the window.

http://gfycat.com/ImpishGrouchyCuscus video of the issue. (Actual app not laggy, video recorded at low fps)

However, comment out this line

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

and the memory usage doesn't go nuts

http://gfycat.com/FearlessSorrowfulGnatcatcher

The commented line only runs once, within the main method. And setting other look and feels via classnames such as nimbus and motif does not cause any issues.

The Netbeans profiler output displays that the lion's share of the memory is being used by the int[] array. Cannot post screenshot here because of link limit.

Any idea why this is happening?

Tried it with Linux Mint as well. Native L&F has the same effect there.